# Отправка сообщений пользователю WordPress из админки

Tags: php, wordpress

Сайт на WordPress. Есть задумка такого функционала: у каждого пользователя есть дополнительное поле с данными, которые заполняет админ сайта. Нужно, чтобы после заполнения этого поля и после нажатия кнопки "Уведомить пользователя", отправлялось письмо на почту пользователя с шаблонным текстом и содержимым этого поля.

Насколько сложно это реализовать и в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Для этого есть масса готовых плагинов с разными фичами

Comment: А можете пару примеров привести, что бы понять подойдут они мне или нет?

Comment: Не подскажу, не юзаю. Но подскажу другое 1.Если речь о многопользовательской системе, то нужно применять спец плагины для управления юзерами. Личка и переписка - лишь малая часть функционала оных. 2. Даже если применяются такие плагины, но в них нет нужно функционала, то в репо всё можно найти с вероятностью 99%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить дополнительные поля, используйте примерно такой код в functions.php. Это рабочий протестированный пример.

```
/**
 * Add extra fields to user profile.
 *
 * @param WP_User $user WP_User object.
 */
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) {
    if ( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'notify', true ) ) {
        $email = array(
            'to'      => $user->user_email,
            'subject' => __( 'User notification', 'text_domain' ),
            'body'    => implode( "\n", array( esc_html( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'message', true ) ) ) ),
            'headers' => '',
        );
        wp_mail( $email['to'], $email['subject'], $email['body'], $email['headers'] );
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'notify', false );
    }
    ?>
    <h3><?php esc_html_e( 'User notification area', 'text_domain' ); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="message"><?php esc_html_e( 'Message', 'text_domain' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="30"><?php echo esc_html( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'message', true ) ); ?></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Notify User', 'text_domain' ); ?></th>
            <td>
                <label for="notify">
                    <input
                        name="notify" type="checkbox" id="notify" value="1"
                        <?php checked( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'notify', true ) ); ?> />
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Check to notify user with the message', 'text_domain' ); ?>
                </label><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

/**
 * Save extra fields in user profile.
 *
 * @param int $user_id User ID.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'update-user_' . $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $result = false;
    if ( isset( $_POST['message'] ) ) {
        $result = $result || update_user_meta( $user_id, 'message', sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['message'] ) );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['notify'] ) ) {
        $result = $result || update_user_meta( $user_id, 'notify', intval( $_POST['notify'] ) );
    }

    return $result;
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
```

В коде два хука - первый выводит поля на страницу настройки пользователя, второй - записывает их в базу при сохранении. Поля представлены текстовой областью и чекбоксом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для отправки сообщения нужно нажать на чекбокс и обновить профиль. Сообщение из текстовой области будет отправлено при перезагрузке страницы.

Первый хук `extra_user_profile_fields()` проверяет, установлен ли чекбокс. Если да, то отправляет сообщение и сбрасывает чекбокс.

Второй хук `save_extra_user_profile_fields()` записывает установленные значения в базу.

Теперь о некоторых особенностях кода, которые полезно понимать.

Код использует функции перевода, вам надо заменить `text_domain` на свой.

Функции содержат описательные комментарии, которые позволяют IDE таким, как PhpStorm, проверять код и предлагать при вводе поля объектов. Например, $user->user_email.

Код содержит функции очистки данных при выводе (`esc_html...`) и валидации (`sanitize_textarea_field()`, `intval()`), которые предотвращают использование опасных данных. Подробнее [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6643/proverka-vhodyashhih-ishodyashhih-dannyh.html#stroki-html).

При сохранении идет проверка с помощью `$result`. Ели никакое из полей не обновилось, надо вернуть false.

WordPress Coding Standards запрещают использовать массив `$_POST` без проверки [nonce](https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/plugins/bezopasnost/odnorazovye-chisla). Проверка реализована с помощью `wp_verify_nonce()`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В качестве доп поля использую плагин ACF. Кнопка должна быть в админке на странице, где идет правка данных пользователя (имя, контактные данные и т.д.).

Comment: Обновил ответ. Сделал чекбокс вместо кнопки, иначе вам придётся идти в ajax, а это ещё дольше объяснять. Про ACF в вашем вопрсе ни слова, поэтому я предпочёл всё же оставить универсальный вариант, работающий без каких=либо плагинов.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за подробное описание) Все работает, даже с плагином ACF.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы создал свой миниплагин, через который бы и можно было бы заполнять поля и отправлять сообщения. Мне кажется так проще, так как всё под полным контролем.

Можно с помощью хуков зарегистрировать дополнительные поля для пользователей и вы сможете их заполнять с помощью стандартного меню (Пользователи -> "пользователь"), но насколько сложно добавить свою кнопку на страницу настроек пользователя сказать не могу, не приходилось.